# What is the purpose of using @PortableProperty

Tags: java, annotations

I recently came across a part of code which has annotation `@PortableProperty` used for variables declared in a DTO. Can anyone please explain what it does and the need for using it?

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct if it serves the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

> Portable marks a class as being eligible for use by a PofAnnotationSerializer. This annotation is only permitted at the class level and is a marker annotation with no members. The following class illustrates how to use Portable and PortableProperty annotations.
>
> A PortableProperty marks a member variable or method accessor as a POF serialized attribute. Whilst the value() and codec() can be explicitly specified they can be determined by classes that use this annotation. Hence these attributes serve as hints to the underlying parser.

Quoted this from doc found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E22843_01/com/tangosol/io/pof/annotation/Portable.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E22843_01/com/tangosol/io/pof/annotation/PortableProperty.html). Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/api_pof.htm#COHDG1358) for more details.

Example:

```
public class Book
        extends ExternalIdEntity
        implements Serializable, PortableObject {
    
    @PortableProperty(1)
    private String id;

    @PortableProperty(3)
    private String parentId;

    @PortableProperty(4)
    private String name;

    @PortableProperty(5)
    private String legalEntityId;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaditya,
I have already gone through those docs.
I want a more detail and specific approach on what exactly purpose does the annotation serve.

Comment: @tushar Not sure what exactly is expected, but to give an example of where its used in my project is: We store different objects in Oracle Coherence cache. While retrieving the data during de-serialization all the fields are expected to be marked with annotation PortableProperty

Comment: That is exactly my question. Why during de-serialization all the fields are expected to be marked with annotation PortableProperty?

Is it that only those fields marked with the annotation will be de-serialized?